# PHP поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: php

Подскажите, как на php искать подстроку в строке и есть ли какие-нибудь свойства и особенности поиска?

Comment: гугл в помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strpos](http://www.php.su/functions/?f=strpos&choice=info) - Возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки.

Answer (score 2):

вы настолько ленивые стали, что не можете прогуглить и взять первый результат поиска. не стыдно, а? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php